# issue in gradle.build file

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-realtime-database

this is my gradle.build code im getting issues like library not found and update versions like that after i have changed to the latest version also im getting that its not supported im a beginner and im creating an chatting app for my final year project.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "afterapps.com.firebaseim"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven{
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1'
    implementation 'frankiesardo:icepick:3.2.0'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    implementation 'com.zsoltsafrany:needle:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    provided 'frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.2.0'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.7'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

https://github.com/MahmoudAlyuDeen/FirebaseIM
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those dependencies are in general quite outdated ...and the Gradle wrapper should be `5.4.1`.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://clojars.org/repo/" }
        maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com" }
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`com.android.support` only works with versions of Firebase libraries, which do not use `androidx`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.afterapps.firebaseim"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    // https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2019-06-17
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1'
    implementation 'frankiesardo:icepick:3.2.0'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.zsoltsafrany:needle:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compileOnly 'frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.2.0'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.7'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
}
```